# Assembly x86: Hiding Cursor

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios

I am creating a selection page for my OS. I want to hide the VGA cursor for a better view. I found ways to do this like putting VGA cursor out of the screen. But is there any other way? I am using BIOS.

Comment: Are you referring to the VGA cursor or the mouse cursor? Are you using the BIOS or avoiding it?

Comment: I am reffering to VGA cursor. I am using the BIOS.

Comment: Add that to the question, it's important. It also seems that S E answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `int 10h` BIOS interrupt with function code `01h` (in `AH`) to set the cursor shape.

The arguments for the function are as follows:

> `CH` = Scan Row Start, `CL` = Scan Row End
>
> Normally a character cell has 8 scan lines, 0-7. So, `CX=0607h` is a normal underline cursor, `CX=0007h` is a full-block cursor. If bit 5 of
>   `CH` is set, that often means "Hide cursor". So `CX=2607h` is an invisible
>   cursor.
>
> Some video cards have 16 scan lines, 00h-0Fh.
>
> Some video cards don't use bit 5 of `CH`. With these, make Start>End (e.g. `CX=0706h`)

This documentation is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H

Comment: Thanks for information. I searched `int 0x10` and other interrupts' documents etc. but I did not see text cursor shaping. I did not think looking to Wikipedia.

Comment: @NafeBon The arguable best resource for DOS and BIOS interfaces is Ralf Brown's interrupt list.  For example, here's the page on [int 10/AH=01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0086.htm).